# struts2 Interceptor's wildcard access

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a action with a wildcard y  I want to access to this variable in the interceptor

Action

```
  @Action(value="{uri}/page",
        results={
            @Result(name=SUCCESS,location="/success.jsp"),
            }
        )
  public String execute(){
    ...
```

Interceptor

```
  public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
         // =( uri is not in the map
        Map<String, Object> params =
              actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getContextMap();
   ...
```

I don't find where I can get the wildcard in the interceptor

EDIT:

I just find how:

```
   public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
         ActionConfig config = actionInvocation.getProxy().getConfig();
         log.info(config.getParams().get("uri"));
```

Comment: not much clear to me.Need more clarifcations

Comment: Rather than editing the question, post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find how:

```
  public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
     ActionConfig config = actionInvocation.getProxy().getConfig();
     log.info(config.getParams().get("uri"));
```

I can do stuff like

localhost/site/campus1/page.action

localhost/site/campus2/page.action

And the interceptor decide if the "campus" exist