# Wild Card Interceptor in Struts2

Tags: struts2, struts2-interceptors

I am new to struts2, I want to create wildcard which maps to Interceptor. I know that you can retrieve value wild card as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876596/struts2-interceptors-wildcard-access)  but how one can call interceptor method for every wild card matching url.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; can you provide some sort of example? Interceptors are configured at the package level; every action in that package will run through its interceptors. What are *you* trying to do?

Comment: @DaveNewton lets say we have url like http://www.sample.com/wildcard/abc. Even if we have http://www.sample.com/wildcard/xyz It should call specific validation interceptor to validate.

Comment: Okay, I'll say that. What should I say next? That doesn't provide any information other than a URL.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have edited comment please have a look.